# Unity says 'Can't convert float to UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I am working on a flight simulator. Somewhere in the code, I use the lift formula and drag formula to generate lift and drag for the plane. Then I say, `float totalForce = lift + drag` then say `rb.AddForce(totalForce)`. But the problem is, on the line `float totalForce = lift + drag`, it shows an error **'Can't convert float to UnityEngine.Vector3'** Here's the code (If you can, please tell me tips on how to make aircraft physics!)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlanePhysics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float liftAngle = 6.2f;
    public float zeroliftAoA = 0f;
    public float stallAngle = 15f;
    
    public Quaternion rotation;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        
        float lift = 9f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f;
        float drag = .04f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f;
        Vector3 TotalForce = lift + drag;
        rb.AddForce(TotalForce);
        float yokeDescend = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float yokeRoll = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        print(yokeDescend);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 1f);
            
        }
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, -1f);
            
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: A vector implies a magnitude (some constant) and some direction that force is applied (some point in space defined in either 2 or 3 dimensions x,y or x,y,z). It looks like you just multiply a bunch of constants together which would give unity the magnitude but no clue what direction to apply it.

Comment: But can you tell me why does Unity throw an error. But thanks for the information!

Comment: It throws an error cause lift+drag is a floating number, a single number, Vector3 requires 3 of them (one per axis), so you are trying to tell Unity to take 1 number and invent the other 2...and Unity can't do that for you

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> float lift = 9f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f;
> float drag = .04f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f;
> Vector3 TotalForce = lift + drag;
> ```

When you create a `Vector3` object your trying to represent one of two things, coordinate in a 3 dimensional space, such as a GameObject at position (x=1,y=2,z=1) in the game world. Or alternatively you're trying to represent a force, such as your case.

When you define a force you must define how large that force is, usually a constant number like `lift`. However, you must also define what *direction* that force should be applied.

In the case of lift the traditional direction would be up since lift.. lifts the plane up.

In order to add a direction to `lift` you could multiply `lift` by the up direction, which in unity is represented by the Vector3 (0, 1, 0).

For example

```cs
float lift = 9f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f * Vector3.up;
```

And you can do the same thing with drag (which I assume is backwards).

For this you want to multiply it with negative forward for the gameobject.

For example

```cs
float drag = .04f * (1.225f * 2.5f * 2.5f) / 2f * 174f * -gameobject.transform.forward;
```

If you want to use a custom direction you can use the Vector3 constructor `new Vector3(x y,z)`

Answer (score 1):

Is not a matter of physics, it is a matter of programming.
'Can't convert float to UnityEngine.Vector3' log error is clear.
[Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) and [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) are different types, so you cannot add a float to a vector3. To add and substract things they must of the same type. There are other weakly type programming languages the would let you add/substract different things, but that is just a pre-defined way if casting that the language has defined so that there is a configurable outcome to give. For example in javascript you can do `var z = "Hello" + 5;` and the outcome is `Hello5`.

If you need to add a force to your rigidbody, it must be a vectorial magnitude, with a module (force quantity) and a direction (force direction), meaning just it should be a `Vector3`.

To add a scalar magnitude as a force to a rigidbody does not make any sense. It could be understood as an added force in the current's body facing direction, for which you would need to do:

```
float totalForceMagnitude = lift + drag;
Vector3 totalForce = transform.forward * totalForceMagnitude; 
rb.AddForce(totalForce );
```

Comment: As a quick sidenote, basically you are adding two floats: Lift and Drag. You are then trying to add a force with just a float. As @rustyBucketBay said, a Vector3 also needs a direction. It is made up of 3 floats, one for each axis. And _that_ is what AddForce takes in as a parameter. So when you try and input a float, the system is unable to use it, because it requires a Vector3, and got a float, **which it can't convert.** :)